# use variable in regexp in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, variables

Is there a way to substitute the [aeiou] within the below code with a variable?  Reason asking is if I later have to do this with consonants, it seems like it would be better to define the variable and use that within the regexp as I imagine it would be cleaner.

```
def word_mutation(word)
  vowels = %w[a e i o u]
  if word.match(/^[aeiou]/)
    return word
  else
    return "consonant-starter"
  end
end
```

So again, I am trying to use or am just curious about trying to use something like:

```
if word.match(/^vowels/)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: irb(main):006:0> word = "vowels" ; myvar = "vowels" ; word.match(/^#{myvar}/

Answer (score 6):

You can use interpolation, as if it were a double quoted string:

```
if word.match(/^#{vowels}/)
```